# how to manually compile a C# project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

Just joined a new project which they are using VC#2008 to build an application. There are several components and many files under one project now. I was asked to setup a build machine to start daily build. The first thing I was told to do is write a batch file to call csc.exe to create an executable manually without the VC#2008 installed.

I am new to C# and I have no idea about the solution. I know the old VC++ can create a makefile for us to do manual build. Does the VC#2008 has similar functionality? Any info and links will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to manually build a Visual C# project is to use msbuild.  The msbuild executable can be passed the VS project file directly and the result will be identical to VS compiling it.

```
msbuild myApp.csproj
```

Msbuild comes as part of the framework and hence can be used without Visual Studio being on the machine.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you *could* write a batch file...

... or you could use [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) as suggested by others...
 ... or — even better — something like [Cruisecontrol.Net](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET)

Answer (score 2):

[MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) is pretty handy but I've found [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) to be easier to use.

Comment: MSBuild seems to be better choice, as *.csproj and *.vbproj are, in fact, MSBuild scripts, so you don't need to write your own scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably take a look at MSBuild.exe - run it from the command line to see the full options.

Comment: In particular, start with `msbuild projectname`